# Tracking MySQL Database Changes

Tags: mysql, history

I'm running MySQL 5.1.36 and have a database used for a web-based help desk system. The database has three tables I'd like to track changes for:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tickets` (
  `TicketNum` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `SubmittedFromIP` tinyblob,
  `SubmittedFromDevice` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EntryDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `ClosedDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `LastName` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FirstName` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Location` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `InventoryNumber` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DeviceName` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Description` text,
  `Notes` text,
  `Agent_ID` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `TotalHoursSpent` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Status` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `Priority` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `LastUpdatedByAgent_ID` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`TicketNum`),
  KEY `ClosedDate` (`ClosedDate`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ticketsolutions` (
  `Entry_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `TicketNum` mediumint(8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `EntryDateTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `HoursSpent` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `Agent_ID` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `EntryText` text,
  `LastUpdatedByAgent_ID` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Entry_ID`),
  KEY `TicketNum` (`TicketNum`),
  KEY `EntryDateTime` (`EntryDateTime`),
  KEY `HoursSpent` (`HoursSpent`),
  KEY `Rating` (`Rating`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tickettagsmap` (
  `TicketNum` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Tag_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `AddedByAgent_ID` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `DateTimeAdded` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`TicketNum`,`Tag_ID`),
  KEY `Tag_ID` (`Tag_ID`),
  KEY `fk_AgentID` (`AddedByAgent_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Based on what I've read, the best way to handle this is to create duplicate tables, only with two extra fields per table:

```
ModifiedDateTime
Action
```

Is this really the best way? Every time even the slightest change is made to a record, the entire record is inserted into its corresponding history table. It seems like a huge waste of space. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: **the best way** depends on your needs, what do you want to know about those changes and what do you want it for.

Comment: I'd like to know when _anything_ changes with the tickets. For example, if a user submits a ticket with a poor description of the problem, an agent would update the description to better describe the problem. I'd still like to see what the original description was, though. I'd also like to track when the ticket's priority changes, when tags are added to the ticket, when the ticket's status changes, etc.

Comment: If you want to recover things to see the state before the change, you'll have to store the full data, which you already know how to do.

Comment: you don't have to log inserts, they are logged in the table themselves!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may or may not be a waste of space depends on typical operations with tables. For `INSERT` and `DELETE` the only way to track is to store all column values. Only for `UPDATE` you can save some space. You can create 2 tables, for instance,

```
update_history_main(id int not null auto_increment primary key,
modify_date datetime not null,
table_involved varchar(50) not null);

update_history_details (id int not null auto_increment primary key,
update_history_main_id int not null,
field_name varchar(100),
old_value varchar(100),
new_value varchar(100),
FOREIGN KEY (update_history_main_id) REFERENCES update_history_main(id)
ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

and add records into these tables after each update. The problem here is that `old_value` and `new_value` columns should be large enough to keep value of any column from your original tables. So you probably need to create another `update_history_details_text_blobs` that tracks only changes in text/blob columns.

**Update**.  Thus, the body of your after update trigger for `tickets` table may look like

```
DELIMITER $$$
 CREATE TRIGGER afterTicketUpdate AFTER UPDATE ON tickets
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
     DECLARE main_id int;
     INSERT INTO update_history_main(modify_date, table_involved) 
      VALUES(NOW(),'tickets';
     SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO main_id;

     IF (new.SubmittedFromDevice != old.SubmittedFromDevice) THEN
      INSERT INTO update_history_details(update_history_main_id, field_name, 
      old_value,new_value) 
     VALUES (main_id, 'SubmittedFromDevice',old.SubmittedFromDevice,
        new.SubmittedFromDevice);
     END IF; // ... check all other fields. 
 END
$$$
```

Comment: +1 for the suggestion to store changes in blobs in a separate table and only store those when they change.

Comment: Thanks, that's a pretty good idea. I don't know how the queries would look for that, though. It seems like it might be extremely complicated. I'll have to play around with it.

Comment: I added an example of trigger that can be used to populate history data (a raw draft, you also need to take care of `NULL` values in conditions that includes nullable colums)

Answer (score 7):

One simple way to do this is

1. Enable MySql logging.
2. Check for updates in the logs.

**Enable logging in MySQL:**

Type the following in mysql backend console.

```
SET GLOBAL log_output = 'TABLE';
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';
```

**Check for updates with queries: (you can customize this to your need)**

```
select argument from mysql.general_log where argument REGEXP '*INSERT*';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create [Triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/triggers.html) for each table, to run when data is inserted, updated, or deleted. Your tracking tables could then hold something like the following:

```
TicketNum          
ModifiedDateTime   
Action
```

and be updated by the trigger each time as needed.